# How to check a string contains 3 dots in python

Tags: python

eg: "ABC.sample.int.int01" like that, only want to check this string contains 3 dots.
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to check if it contains *exactly* three dots? Can you tell more about the original problem you're solving?

Comment: `"ABC.sample.int.int01".count('.')` ... ?

Comment: `"ABC.sample.int.int01".count('.') == 3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it like this, with `count` attribute of `str` in python. If it is equal to 3, then your strings actually contains exactly 3 dots.

```py
if 'ABC.sample.int.int01'.count('.') == 3:
   ...
else:
   ...
```